# Re-evaluate MySQL subquery for each INSERT

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to **duplicate rows** in the same table. Table A has **no auto_increment** (unfortunately).

```
INSERT INTO A (id, foreign_id, value)
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM A), 2, value
        FROM A WHERE foreign_id = 1;
```

But `(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM A)` is calculated once, so it will always return the same ID. At the second row insertion the query will fail (duplicate primary key).

I tried that first:

```
INSERT INTO A (id, foreign_id, value)
    SELECT MAX(id)+1, 2, value
        FROM A WHERE foreign_id = 1;
```

But the `MAX(id)+1` takes into account `WHERE foreign_id = 1`, so there's no guarantee that I'll get a non-used ID.

How can I proceed to either:

- Have a subquery that is re-calculated for each `INSERT`
- Or more generally: duplicate rows in my table given there's no auto_increment

Comment: Using `max(id) + 1` to generate a unique number is bound to fail in a multi-user system. You should use an autoincrement column instead

Comment: am I correct in that you're not really duplicating, your trying to create a separate record with a different ID, and a foreign_ID of 2 but with the same value as those records with a foreign_ID of 1?  So if you have the following 2 records: {1,1,1}{3,1,2} you want a new set that has {4,2,1} and {5,2,2}?  If so, how many records are you looking to "duplicate" and do they HAVE to follow sequentially the existing records?  instead of {4,2,1} and {5,2,2} would {4,2,1} and {6,2,2}? work?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I know, this is just a big script, no multi-users or anything.

Comment: @xQbert Yes you completely got it. I don't care about the primary key, I just want to duplicate the "content" of the row (the other columns), with a new foreign ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using variables?

```
SET @max=SELECT MAX(id);
INSERT INTO A (id, foreign_id, value)
    SELECT @max:=@max+1, 2, value
        FROM A WHERE foreign_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, first time I use variables. I'll give it a little more time if there are other possible solutions before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments I believe this would work then.
The trick is you can't use +1 as you found (unless you use variables) but you can use the existing ID and add it to the max which will give you a unique ID each time.

```
INSERT INTO A (id, foreign_id, value)
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM A)+ID, 2, value
        FROM A WHERE foreign_id = 1;
```

Comment: IMO: fritzfromLondon's answer is better if you want to keep a sequence w/o spacing.  Mine will retain similar spacing to that of existing records (incase there are gaps and for some reason you want to maintain them)

Comment: Interesting, that's simpler, even though I'd be careful with reaching the maximum number allowed by the column's type.